# Mixing GPU'S when building a rig

Tags: gpu

I was wondering if you could let me know if I would run into any issues buy building a small duo card mining rig with the ASUS 3060ti and a GIGABYTE RTX3070? Would anyone recommend a motherboard for such a project?

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine. Both are cuda and as long as you use a cuda miner ,you should be fine.

If you were using nvidia combined with amd , all you needed to do is choose a miner that suports both .

Hope my answer helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. Have you any advice on the most cost effective motherboard for these cards?